# Updating a document library list ltem in ASP.NET code behind file

Tags: 2007, development, document-library, list-item

I am trying to update a list item's custom property in asp.net code behind file but getting Error 500 without any explanation or further error, while debugging I realized it happens while calling update method for item, I tried same code in Console application for same list and it worked perfectly. Here's the code,

```
    List<string> someStringList = new List<string>();

    foreach(string sD in someString)
        someStringList.Add(sD);

    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
    {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(webURL))
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

            int items = web.Lists[listName].ItemCount;

                foreach (SPListItem listItem in web.Lists[listName].Items)
                {
                    if (listItem != null && !someStringList.Contains(listItem.Name))
                    {
                        listItem.BreakRoleInheritance(true);// = "ItWorksButNot";
                        // listItem.Update();

                        listItem["Is Document Important"] = "True";

                        listItem.Update();
                        //listItem.SystemUpdate(false);
                        //web.Lists[listName].Update();
                    }
                }

            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        }
    });
```

Now custom column Name is fine and it does exists as I can check it while debugging.

Comment: I fear I already know the answer, but... the log doesn't contain any other info that provides more detail on the problem right?

Comment: Nope not really, but I made it work now somehow not sure how tho as I didn't really changed any code, thanks for looking at it tho :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't really changed much in code but it started working now, I don't really know what was the cause of error 500 either, however changes I made to code includes following,

```
  List<string> someStringList = new List<string>();
// removing elevated privileges didn't really changed anything but I removed it as 
// I know user will have permissions for updating list item.
    foreach(string sD in someString)
        someStringList.Add(sD);

        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(webURL))
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            int items = web.Lists[listName].ItemCount;

                foreach (SPListItem listItem in web.Lists[listName].Items)
                {
                    if (listItem != null)
                    {
                        if(someStringList.Contains(listItem.Name))
                             Continue;
                        else
                        {
                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                            listItem["Is Document Important"] = "True";
                            listItem.Update();
                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
```

Comment: Some operations seems to reset the "AllowUnsafeUpdate" flag - maybe that was the problem. If you have some spare time, I would have a go with the original code you posted in the question and see if just before the call to update web.AllowUnsafeUpdates is still true.

Comment: Sorry that was more like a typing error, I turned off updates after updating list item.

Comment: Hehe, didn't even notice that. What I was suggesting is that in my experience sometimes the AllowUnsafeUpdates is reset to false by some internal operation - so it is better to set it just before the problematic step. I was wondering if that could be your case - basically I was asking myself if in your original code the flag was still set when .Update() is called, or in between SharePoint decided to reset it.

Answer (score 1):

try these block of code..it may solve your problem..

```
    List<string> someStringList = new List<string>();

foreach(string sD in someString)
    someStringList.Add(sD);
SPSite csite=SPContext.Current.Site;
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
{

    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(csite.ID,csite.SystemAccount.UserToken))
    {
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

        int items = web.Lists[listName].ItemCount;

            foreach (SPListItem listItem in web.Lists[listName].Items)
            {
                if (listItem != null && !someStringList.Contains(listItem.Name))
                {
                    listItem.BreakRoleInheritance(true);// = "ItWorksButNot";
                    // listItem.Update();

                    listItem["Is Document Important"] = "True";

                    listItem.Update();
                    //listItem.SystemUpdate(false);
                    //web.Lists[listName].Update();
                }
            }

        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    }
    }
});
```